# Understanding Maps SDK for Android pricing for displaying preset locations

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I’m working on an Android app for my final year college project that will use the Maps SDK for Android to display a limited number of preset locations on a map e.g. the Central Park, NYC and maybe other 10-15 places using their latitudes and longtitudes.

I plan to show these locations and load them on the phone screen about say a maximum of 50 times (to give a demonstration to my faculty).

Here’s an example of how I’m implementing this in my code:

```
mMap = googleMap;
LatLng jdpLatLng= new LatLng(v: 26.2389, v1: 73.0243);
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position (jdpLatLng).title("Jodhpur");
mMap.addMarker (markerOptions);
mMap.moveCamera (CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(jdpLatLng));
mMap.animateCamera (CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(jdpLatLng, v. 16f));
```

I’m trying to understand if my usage of the Maps SDK for Android will be covered under the $200 monthly credit provided by Google Maps Platform. Will I be charged for this usage or will it be free? Any insights or guidance would be much appreciated. Because I'm not sure about the APIs used. Sorry for the naive question

Comment: First of all, I would like to suggest that you file a support case if you want to inquire about their pricing: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#creating-a-support-case. You also might want to check the documentation first. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing